# Deposit on EtherDelta Not Working

Tags: gas, gas-price, etherdelta

No matter what I set gas price to on EtherDelta.com when I try to make a deposit I get this error

`You tried to send an Ethereum transaction but there was an error. Make sure you have enough ETH in your "Wallet" column to pay for the gas fee. If you already have a pending transaction (enter your address on Etherscan to find out), please wait for it to confirm, or increase your "gas price" (in the upper right dropdown) and try again.`

I have 1.519 ETH available in my balance and I've tried to deposit as little as 1ETH (0.519 available for fee).

This site says recommended gas price is 47 https://ethgasstation.info/
I don't see how a gas price of 150 and 0.519 ETH aren't enough

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have the transaction id of the failed transaction?

Comment: Same there, did you find a solution??

Answer (score 2):

Enable "contract" and "browser" on your ledger

Comment: This could be the answer, but just to note: the OP didn't say anything about using a Ledger Nano S.